# Understanding the logic

Tags: java, logic

I have the following homework problem:

> Given an array of scores, return true if there are scores of 100 next to each other in the array. The array length will be at least 2.

Does this question mean that the numbers in the array should be exactly divisible by 100? So 1 will also make the program return true if it is in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is to check if the number "100" occurs consecutively in the Array.

```
12 45 100 100 65 45 ....
```

this array has 100 next to each other

Answer (score 6):

You should check if there are two values exactly equal to 100 next to each other I believe.

Comment: +1 "return true if there are scores of 100 next to each other in the array"

Comment: @PeterLawrey is "bon public" (easy to please?) :-)

Comment: +1 So many upvotes for a question belonging to english.stackexchange.com ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As far as the question makes sense to me , you should check if any of the values are 100 next to each other in the array. For that , a simple loop would suffice.

```
for (int i=0;i<score.length-1;i++){
    if (score[i]==100&&score[i+1]==100)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

In case you want to check for divisibility with 100 , just use this if statement instead of the one above . However , this is not what the question asks for

```
if (score[i]%100==0&&score[i+1]%100==0)
```

All this is asuming that the array is an integer array